No fields matching the criteria 'None' were found in the dataset
I'm trying to load a spark dataframe via petastorm 0.12 following the tutorial given in the petastorm-spark-converter-tensorflow notebook. Essentially my code is the following. The error described in the title is raised in the with statement. (Doesn't happen when directly creating a TFDatasetContextManager via train_context_manager = converter_train.make_tf_dataset(BATCH_SIZE) though.
from petastorm import TransformSpec
from petastorm.spark import make_spark_converter

spark.conf.set(SparkDatasetConverter.PARENT_CACHE_DIR_URL_CONF, "file:///dbfs/tmp/petastorm/cache"

converter_train = make_spark_converter(DF_TRAIN)
with converter_train.make_tf_dataset(BATCH_SIZE) as X_train:
  pass


The dataset definitely isn't empty. I also tried to apply a TransformSpec explicitly selecting my target columns
with converter_train.make_tf_dataset(
    BATCH_SIZE,
    transform_spec=TransformSpec(selected_fields=[TRAIN_COL])
) as X_train:

Btw the same happens with converter_train.make_torch_dataloader

When you receive an error message like this, the key is the Python value None. It means that whatever reference you are trying to use has not been instantiated, so it does not refer to anything. Commonly this occurs when you call a method that is supposed to return some reference but for some reason does not. But it is not clear exactly which value is causing the failure. Try stepping through the code with the debugger to gather more details.

The error message really is misleading - the reason was that the column I read was of type Array<Array<float>>. It turns out that the invoked make_batch_reader of petastorm cannot handle this type:

NOTE: only scalar columns or array type (of primitive type element) columns are currently supported.

